# Spring boot batch : process many xml files don't work while changing name's file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I process many xml files using spring boot batch. Task is scheduled every 10s, files are processed then deleted.

```
    @Bean
public Job importProductJob() {
    return jobs.get("importProductJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(productLoadStep())
            .on("FAILED").end()
            .from(productLoadStep()).on("*").to(moveFileStep())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step productLoadStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("productLoadStep")
            .<Product, Product>chunk(1000)
            .reader(multiItemReader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public MultiResourceItemReader<Product> multiItemReader() {
  ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
  org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] resources = null;
  try {
    resources = patternResolver.getResources(Constantes.PREFIXE + inputResources);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("error reading files", e);
  }
  return new MultiResourceItemReaderBuilder<Product>()
      .name("multiItemReader").delegate(reader())
      .resources(resources)
      .setStrict(true)
      .build();
}

@Bean
public StaxEventItemReader<Product> reader() {
    
    Jaxb2Marshaller productMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    productMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Product.class);
    
    return new StaxEventItemReaderBuilder<Product>()
            .name("reader")
            .addFragmentRootElements("productRecord")
            .unmarshaller(productMarshaller)
            .strict(false)  // catch exception when resource doesn't exist, and log nothing
            .build();        
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Product, Product> processor() {
    return new ProductItemProcessor();
}


@Bean
public ItemWriter<Product> writer() {
    JpaItemWriter<Product> writer = new JpaItemWriter<Product>();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Step moveFileStep() {
    FileMovingTasklet task = new FileMovingTasklet();
    ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] resources = null;
          try {
            resources = patternResolver
            .getResources(Constantes.PREFIXE + inputResources);
          } catch(Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
    
    task.setResources(resources);
    task.setTargetResources(targetResources);
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("moveFile")
            .tasklet(task)
            .build();
}
```

** The main class **

```
 @SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;
     
    @Autowired
    Job job;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchConfiguration.class, args);
    }
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * ?")
    public void perform() throws Exception {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, params);
    }
}
```

I put 3 files in inputFolder : p_1.xml, p_2.xml and p_3.xml and i lunch the program. The three files are processed and deleted.
The problem :

- If i put again in inputFolder another file having as name p_1.xml, p_2.xml or p_3.xml ; it is processed
- If i put an xml file with another name, exp : p.xml or p_4.xml ; it's ignored.

**Question :**
How is it possible to process any file with the rignt pattern (p_5.xml, .. p_lqdfjsmfqlkjdf.xml) ?

Thank you.

**Second problem**
Finally it's working. I add @StepScope to multiItemReader() method, but i've another problem now :
i've two steps, the first one (read xml and write in db) is ok. But the second step ( moveFileStep() ) which move processed files to another directory, fail. I added @StepScope, but still not working.

**Error :**

```
    2021-08-25_13:35:57.483 ERROR o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:785)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at com.cegelec.datex.Application.main(Application.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=importProductJob at state=importProductJob.step1 with exception
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:178)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.moveFileStep': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:383)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:195)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.getName(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.isStepRestart(JobFlowExecutor.java:86)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
```

**Third problem :**
Steps are executed correctly when i lunch the application from eclipse. But when i lunch the executable jar, the second step (move files) is ok, but not the first one. In first step, the multiItemReader() methed locate files, but don't read them and all values are empty.
I still need help :-(

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236509/discussion-on-question-by-langar-spring-boot-batch-process-many-xml-files-don).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by modifing the step method moveFileStep() this way :

```
@Bean
public Step moveFileStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("moveFileStep")
        .tasklet(fileMovingTasklet())
        .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Tasklet fileMovingTasklet() {

    // work to do

    return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
    };
}
```